# MLflow conda_env offline environment

Tags: conda, mlflow

We want to use the [MLproject `conda_env`](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html#mlproject-file) feature in an offline environment, in order to reproduce the models in various computers.

When running on an internet connected computer we see that the `conda environment` is created by downloading the packages from anaconda.

1. Is there an option to run `MLflow run .` with an `MLproject` file that will use an **existing conda environment**? (without creating a new one based on the `conda.yaml` file). Setting the [MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html#project-environments) environment just points to the location folder where to create the environment. But I can't find how to specify an existing environment.
2. If Is there an option to point to a [conda pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) file?

**UPDATE**
I guess this [github issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2984) is related

Answer (score 0):

You can run your project with the `--no-conda` flag like described [here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html#running-projects).
This will run in the current environment and ignores conda_env.

Example of usage: `mlflow models serve --model-uri /path/to/my/model --no-conda`

Comment: However I do want to run with `conda` . see the Update github issue